# Generate specific Regex PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, html-parsing

Here's my problem, I want to parse this line of code in Regex.

```
<div id="attachment_371" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 466px"></div>
```

Inside of this div there are others divs. I try to display these nested divs but they don't appear.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Its not regex but this is better than using regex.

```
$innerHTML = '';
$html = '<html><body>
    <div id="attachment_371" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 466px">
       <p>Test</p>
       <div>some random content</div>
       <p>Test1</p>
       <div>Some more</div>
    </div>
 </body></html>';


$source=new DOMdocument();
$source->loadHTML($html);
$path=new DOMXpath($source);
$dom=$path->query("*/div[@id='attachment_371']/*");
if (!$dom==0) {
    foreach ($dom as $dom2) {
        $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
        $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($dom2,true));
        $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
    }
}
echo $innerHTML;
```

should give you

```
<p>Test</p>
<div>some random content</div>
<p>Test1</p>
<div>Some more</div>
```

or if you just want the nested divs and ignore everything else then use

```
$source=new DOMdocument();
$source->loadHTML($html);
$path=new DOMXpath($source);
$dom=$path->query("*/div[@id='attachment_371']/div");
if (!$dom==0) {
    foreach ($dom as $dom2) {
        $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
        $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($dom2,true));
        $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
    }
}
echo $innerHTML;
```

which would give you

```
<div>some random content</div>
<div>Some more</div>
```